# How to beat second and third practice mission?

Tags: naruto-ultimate-ninja

On the second and third "practice" missions in Naruto Ultimate Ninja, you have to beat the opponent and then collect a certain item (in the second mission it is the "Special Ninja Tools" and in the third it is the "Weight of Gut".) I have scoured the levels and can't find them.

Where are theses objects or how do I get them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you need to get the item during the level before you've defeated your opponent (maybe that part was obvious to you). You get items by hitting the training dummies that appear in the background, or any of the other destructible environment objects like the lanterns near Ichiraku Ramen.

You can also get items by hitting some characters in the background like Konohamaru in the second practice mission in front of the Hokage's Faces.

[image: I circled two of the many objects you could destroy in this screenshot.]

If I remember correctly, having certain items by the end of a mission is a pretty common condition, too.

Comment: I know how to get items, but I have yet to ever get one of the ones needed to complete the mission. I don't even know what they look like.

Comment: As far as I know they drop 'randomly.' I'm pretty sure Special Ninja Tools is the gold shuriken, and Weight of Gut is a red and tan scroll. Looking through the game manual, the other two usable items are Support Item (it's tan, kind of shaped like a shield) and Scroll of Instant Body (a scroll with a leaf on it).

Comment: Okay, but I have used up the time limit destroying item-giving  things, and have yet to have the item I need drop. :/ Maybe I can look up the percentage chance of them dropping.

Comment: (This might not be that helpful to you but) I took out my copy when I was answering this and I had about 12 counts or so when I found the item and finished it. Also, yeah, there's surprisingly little information on this game... Maybe I'll do some naruto research tonight :P

Comment: So I tried again to get the item, and ran out of time before ever finding the item. When you went and got the item with 12 ticks remaining, did you receive it from destroying a training dummy or what?

Comment: Yeah I got it from a dummy. I'll replay it a couple more times soon and update my answer with more info tonight.

Comment: Okay! I finally figured it out (I'm just now answering it on here, though =P). 

What I didn't realize was that the Weight of Gut and Special Ninja Tools were just normal items!(The one that slows you down and the one that throws different ninja stars). I thought that they were special items that only appeared when playing the practice mission! Thanks for trying to help me, it turned out it was a misinterpretation on my end.

Answer (score 0):

What I didn't realize was that the Weight of Gut and Special Ninja Tools were just normal items! (The one that slows you down and the one that throws different ninja stars). I thought that they were special items that only appeared when playing the practice mission!